# Redirect from HTTPs to HTTP in Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I got several sites running under the same IP with name-based virtual host support activated:

- myexamplesite0.com  <-- HTTP
- myexamplesite1.com  <-- HTTPs
- myexamplesite2.com  <-- HTTP

In my apache config (*/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl*) I have a rewrite rule to redirect requests from HTTPs to HTTP.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect to HTTP
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?myexamplesite1\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </IfModule>
    [...]
```

As you see, everything exept for myexamplesite1.com gets redirected to a HTTP-version.

Now, the problem is, that if I type https://myexamplesite2.com, the browser first asks for the confirmation of the snake-oil certificate (i.e. the requrest lands in default-ssl). Once the certificate is accepted, the redirection to the HTTP version takes place. I just don't get why.

I want the redirection first resp. without the certificate issue. Is that possible? What am I missing?

I would accept to show a non-existent HTTPs-site as well, if this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to redirect the client to HTTP site before the browser shows the "Bad certificate/No CA" warning.

But their is a problem... SSL/TLS is lower down in the network stack than HTTP.
After you have a secure socket only then the HTTP protocol is kicked in.

So no. you cannot do that, otherwise HTTPS will be totally broken to MITM attacks...